# Gameobject destroy fails inside destructor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, destructor

I have an object, which contains a list of GameObjects. I wish to destroy all of these GameObjects in its destructor.

However, when I attempt to call GameObject.Destroy() from inside the destructor, it seems to halt execution (the line after GameObject.Destroy() never executes, but the line before it does)

If i copy and paste exactly the same code into a function called not_a_destructor() and call that instead, it works perfectly. What gives? I've got it working, but I would really like to understand what's going on.

Destructor and not_a_destructor() code:

```
    // Destructor DOES NOT work
    ~MoveAction(){
        for(int i = 0; i < arrows.Count; i++){
            Debug.Log("wasd");
            GameObject.Destroy(arrows[i]);
            Debug.Log("asdf");
        }
    }

    // Identical code, calling not_a_destructor() works perfectly
    public void not_a_destructor(){
        for(int i = 0; i < arrows.Count; i++){
            Debug.Log("PRETEND DESTRUCTOR!");
            GameObject.Destroy(arrows[i]);
            Debug.Log("GameObject destroyed successfully");
        }
    }
```

As requested in comments, a full copy of the class:

```
public class Action
{
    public int type;
    public string debug_string;
    public GameObject ui_pill; // Only present for Actions created on the client
}

public class MoveAction : Action
{
    public int type = ActionType.MOVE;
    public MapHex origin;
    public List<MapHex> route; // Intermediate hexes travelled through during the move (includes target_hex)
    public Fleet fleet;
    private List<GameObject> arrows = new List<GameObject>(); // Arrows for the graphical representation of the pending move on the tactical map

    public MapHex target_hex {
        get {
            return route[route.Count - 1];
        }
    }
    public string debug_string {
        get {
            return "MOVE ACTION WITH FLEET: " + fleet.name;
        }
    }
    public MoveAction(Fleet _fleet, List<MapHex> _route){
        fleet = _fleet;
        route = _route;
        origin = fleet.planned_position;
        update_arrows_from_route();
    }

    public void update_arrows_from_route(){
        Material default_material = new Material(Shader.Find("Sprites/Default"));
        // Create one arrow for every hex we will pass through.
        MapHex last = fleet.planned_position;
        foreach (MapHex hex in route){
            // Create arrow from last to hex
            GameObject arrow_gameobj = new GameObject();
            arrow_gameobj.name = "move_order_arrow";
            LineRenderer line_renderer = arrow_gameobj.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
            line_renderer.material = default_material;
            line_renderer.SetColors(fleet.owner.color, fleet.owner.color);
            line_renderer.positionCount = 2;
            arrow_gameobj.layer = layers.tactical_map;

            Vector3[] line_points = new Vector3[]{last.position, hex.position};
            line_renderer.SetPositions(line_points);
            line_renderer.startWidth = 0.1f;
            line_renderer.endWidth = 0.1f;
            arrows.Add(arrow_gameobj);

            last = hex;
        }
    }

    public void not_a_destructor(){
        for(int i = 0; i < arrows.Count; i++){
            Debug.Log("PRETEND DESTRUCTOR!");
            GameObject.Destroy(arrows[i]);
            Debug.Log("GameObject destroyed successfully");
        }
    }

    ~MoveAction(){
        for(int i = 0; i < arrows.Count; i++){
            Debug.Log("wasd");
            GameObject.Destroy(arrows[i]);
            Debug.Log("asdf");
        }
    }
```

Comment: what does the GameObject.Destroy() do?  The finalizer/destructors a single threaded I believe, possible a dead lock..

Comment: It seems to just halt, no error or anything. So a deadlock would fit the symptoms, but its an *extremely* simple gameobject i'm destroying. It only contains a single LineRenderer, I have no idea how destroying that could cause a deadlock.

Comment: The are no destructors in C#, only finalizers. And since finalizers are called by the GC it is very well possible that this happens on a different thread than the main threads (where you should be calling Unity specific methods like `GameObject.Destroy`)

Comment: That's what it sounds like @UnholySheep, my answer below is pretty much in line with that theory.

Comment: Can you show your complete script ... Is this a `MonoBehaviour`? Because in this case it would not be allowed to have any constructor or deconstructer ...

Comment: Or is this maybe done on a background thread where nothing of the Unity API may be called?

Comment: I've updated the question with a full copy of the class and superclass as requested, it's a very barebones affair, not much going on. It is not a monobehaviour. @derHugo

Comment: It seems like a few people agree that you can't call unity methods from "finalizers" because they might be on a different thread?

Comment: Generally speaking you should avoid using finalizers in C# unless absolutely necessary. Apart from not having any idea when they will run they can also lead to performance degradation as the Garbage Collector has to handle objects with finalizers differently than regular objects (see also articles like this one for more points: https://www.viva64.com/en/b/0437/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its probable best to use more of Unity and less of C#, there is a good callback called OnDestroy() which would be a fine place to destroy all the arrows. If execution of your unity code depends on running a finalizer on something, this is a very strong code smell.

Unless you are using IO in a way that REQUIRES an action to happen in a finalizer (possibly things like releasing an IO resource), its best to leave them empty, and put Unity code inside Unity callbacks